# How to I iterate a character loop counter in Java?

Tags: java, loops, character, counter

The problem states - "Write a for loop that iterates a character loop counter from 'c' to 'h', inclusive of both characters, that print the character loop counter each time with System.out.print(). Outside (and after) the loop, terminate the line with an empty System.out.println()."

```
int x =1;

for (char y = 'c'; y>=2 && y<=7; y++) {
    System.out.println(y);
    x++;
}

System.out.println();
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 7):

Chars can be compared directly to chars. This is **not** the case for strings.

```
for(char y = 'c'; y <= 'h'; y++){
    System.out.print(y);
}
System.out.println();
```

I changed a println to a print due to the instruction:

> that print the character loop counter each time with System.out.print()